# How can I run Symfony 4 in production mode?

Tags: symfony, configuration, profiler

I am using the Symfony profiler. But I actually only want to make it visible in the Dev mode. But when I push the data via git on my server and open the website, I see the profiler. That does not make sense of cause, but I do not know how to remove it.

I was looking for the file called `config/config_dev.yml` and `config/config.yml` because I would think that in `config/config.yml` I should just set to:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false
```

But I do not have any config.yml files. Do I have to create them?

Comment: when you see profiler on your server, you're running it in dev mode there - is that what you want? otherwise you'll have to make sure to run it in production mode on your server.

Comment: @LBA Oh, no of course not, I want to run production mode. How can I do that?

Comment: then please re-phrase your question or open a new one. it's a huge difference between hiding the profiler in dev mode vs running the application in prod mode

Comment: @LBA Yeah, this is true! Didn't think of this

Comment: [Start here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html). Pay particular attention to setting env variables.  One thing to point out, the profile bar code should not even be installed in production.  I see you accepted the answer below which is fine as a starting point.  Just be aware that is it wrong and insecure if you plan on deploying real applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your server, copy your `.env.dist` (if you have one) to `.env`, and set `APP_ENV=prod`

If you don't yet have a `.env` file, create one at the root of you project, and put `APP_ENV=prod` in it.

That being said, note that best practice is to use server level configuration in production env. Reference link : https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production

**EDIT (based on the comments) for your information :**

`.env` is a file where you will mainly put your global configuration. The `.dist` variant is meant to be added to git, it won't be used by symfony but is useful for the developpers (including you) to have a default config file to rely on.

Basically, when they'll pull the project for the first time, they'll copy this file to `.env` then adjust the lines/config to their liking.
The `.env` must not be added to git for it will be the file that will be used by symfony. If you add it to git, each time you will push your local work then pull from your server, it will replace your server configuration with your local one.

Comment: I see now, that on my server I have 2 files `.env.dist` AND `.env` Do I have to delete one of them?

Comment: No, just open your .env, and search for the APP_ENV line, change it to prod if it exits, otherwise just write it. It's weird than you have a .env without knowing about it though, you might consider remove it from git if it has been added to the repository. Otherwise it will be overwritten each time you will pull on your server.

Comment: No, I knew I have the env. file, I was working with it, just didn't know the option APP_ENV. It is ignored by git.

Comment: Now I understand the meaning of .env.dist :) Thank you

Comment: Yes, seems like the ignore entry is added by default by the framework-bundle. Glad it fixed your problem.

Comment: BTW it's not good practice to use `.env` in production. In production you should set environment variables on web-server level

Comment: True, although it's a little bit less convenient. Thanks for pointing it out, I added it to the answer with ref link.

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev Really? Why is that so?

Comment: @Jarla I suppose because of security reasons. Also, author of Dotenv doesn't recommend to use it in production: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#usage-notes

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev Ok thank you, I will think about this